# Connection closed error on server sent events

Tags: asp.net-web-api, server-sent-events

I created a server-sent event on ASP.NET Web API using the following codes :

```
namespace SpaServerSide.Controllers
{
    public class SSEController : ApiController
    {

        static readonly ConcurrentQueue<StreamWriter> ConnectedClients = new ConcurrentQueue<StreamWriter>();
        static System.Threading.Timer _dd = new System.Threading.Timer(OnTimerEvent, null, 0, 1000);


        [Route("api/sse")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            var Response = Request.CreateResponse();
            Response.Content = new PushStreamContent((Action< Stream, HttpContent, TransportContext>)OnStreamAvailabe, "text/event-stream");
            return Response;
        }

        private static void OnStreamAvailabe(Stream stream, HttpContent headers, TransportContext context)
        {
            var clientStream = new StreamWriter(stream);
            ConnectedClients.Enqueue(clientStream);         
        }

        static void OnTimerEvent(object state)
        {
            _dd.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
            try
            {
                var jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var message = jsSerializer.Serialize(new { msg = "Server send this response on " + DateTime.Now.ToString() });
                foreach (var clientStream in ConnectedClients)
                {
                    clientStream.WriteLine("data:" + message + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
                    clientStream.Flush();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                _dd.Change(1000, 1000);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Then, I connect to this server with javascript using the following snippets :

```
var evtSource = new EventSource("http://localhost:5587/api/sse");

        evtSource.onopen = function(e){             
            alert("Opened");
        }

        evtSource.onmessage = function(e){
            console.log(e);
            alert("Response Received.");
        }

        evtSource.onerror = function (e) {
            alert('error');
        };
```

However, an exception occurs. The message is :The remote host closed the connection. How did this happen? And for further studies, when does the server-sent event trigger? Can it be controlled manually?

Comment: From what I can see, you are trying to reimplement [SignalR](http://signalr.net/)?

Comment: They said it's a new feature of HTML 5, called server-sent events.

Comment: Yes, but please take a look at the link I provided in my previous comment: SignalR does exactly what you want (bi-directional communication) using the best protocol for both client and server (Server-Side Events included).